# What to do about negative score to a good answer?

Tags: support, voting

I've answered this question:

[Python convert TXT to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731736/python-convert-txt-to-csv/34731889#34731889)

Got a comment with "You nailed it!" and still end up with a -1 :(

What can I do about this?

Comment: One thing to remind you,never complain downvotes for yourself in meta or you may receive more downvotes

Comment: A code-only answer. I don't know if I ever upvoted such, but I downvoted plenty because *they plain aren't that useful*.

Comment: OP I edited your answer into somewhat better shape. If you want it to be even better add another bit of information to your answer, such as why you recommend this approach, and what the limits of your approach are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see several things that could lead to downvotes in your answer:

- It's a code dump. This is unlikely to help anyone but the OP, and even them only on a shallow, instant-gratification level. Code dumps are almost never useful in any future context.
- You <s>have</s> had noise in your answer (i.e. "Have fun"), which is generally discouraged.
- Your comment "You may upvote/accept this answer" sounds arrogant on first glance.

If you improve those things, I'm sure your answer can get a few upvotes going and maybe the downvoter(s) will retract their downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

I am not the downvoter, but I can imagine, that his critique on your answer was, that it is basically just a code dump. Though it seems to be the correct solution, try to add one or two explanatory sentences, *why* it is.
This helps the OP understand his mistake and prevents him from doing a similar one again. (Give a man a fish...)

There are additional problems with your answer, that @Magisch has pointed out. As this answer is accepted, I cite him (with full approval):

> - It's a code dump. This is unlikely to help anyone but the OP, and even them only on a shallow, instant-gratification level. Code dumps are almost never useful in any future context.
> - You <s>have</s> had noise in your answer (i.e. "Have fun"), which is generally discouraged.
> - Your comment "You may upvote/accept this answer" sounds arrogant on first glance.

I also want to consent with his advice:

> If you improve those things, I'm sure your answer can get a few upvotes going and maybe the downvoter(s) will retract their downvotes.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, But in this case, he said in the comment he **got it** ...  anyway, You (as the other comments here say) are correct

Comment: What have I done wrong in the answer for this question to get a negative score: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731685/dbms-output-put-doesnt-print-anything

Comment: @Nitish - Maybe stack-overflow should make it the down-vote public

Comment: I don't mind getting a downvote, if it can improve my questioning or answering abilities. For the above question's answer, I still don't know what I did wrong. So there is no scope of improving my answer. Maybe stackoverflow should include a compulsory comment field which should be filled when someone upvotes or downvotes.

Comment: `Maybe stackoverflow should include a compulsory comment field which should be filled when someone upvotes or downvotes.` Maybe you should have skimmed through a few pages of Meta to see that it has been discussed gazillions times and is widely rejected by the community.

Comment: @EricD.: Maybe you can tell me what I did wrong in answering that question before lecturing me on the Meta.

Comment: @Nitish Your answer to the question is not what I'm talking about. I'm only referencing the quote I've included in my comment, about your idea of a compulsory comment for a downvote, which has been rejected *numerous times* by community. Your "maybe SO should ..." made me cringe and made me think "well maybe *you* should ..." Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Nitish Your suggestion has been discussed on Stackoverflow dozens of times before, and has always been very widely rejected.

Comment: @EricD.: So you mean to say that there is no way to address my concerns in SO? For example this question itself. Look at the score. I'm now afraid that if I ask more questions even my account might be deleted.

Comment: @Nitish I never said such a thing, don't put words in my mouth. Read my comment again. Thanks. :)

Comment: @EricD.: Sorry. But I'm regularly seeing people being ridiculed instead of being politely told about SO policies. Its like those internet trolls or school bullying. If this continues, people are going to turn away and look at some alternate sites. Its not about your comment, but I was already frustrated by the ego of some people on SO and thought that you were someone similar :)

Comment: @Nitish I understand, don't worry. // And maybe my comment was a bit direct, so I apologize for that. Of course it wasn't my intention to hurt anyone's feelings. It's just that this comment+downvote thing is such a tired cliché on Meta that I couldn't *not react*. ;)